Analytically show the maximum number of roots of the transcendental equation
How many roots can we obtain from the equation by considering all possibilities of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ ?
$$x = a + b.\sin(x) - \sin(x^2)$$
I had just written a  piece of code to verify the number of roots and got maximum 5.

Can we prove analytically the maximum number of roots exhibited by this equation?

If $a=0,b=100$ then the equation already get more than $5$ solutions, imho maybe there are infinite by keep increasing the values of $b$.

The number of real solutions is unbounded.
Write the equation as $\sin(x) = f(x)$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{x - a + \sin(x^2)}{b}$.
For fixed $a$ and $N$, take $b$ large enough that $(2 N \pi - |a| - 1)/b < 1$, thus $|f(x)| < 1$ if $|x| \le 2  N \pi$.  In each interval $[2n \pi, 2(n+1)\pi]$ for $-N \le n < N$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is at least one solution of $\sin(x) = f(x)$, so there are at least $2N$ solutions in all.
